# GNU screen startup is really slow

Tags: linux, rhel, gnu-screen

I connect to a RHEL 5.7 server via Putty or VNC (not sure it matters) but when I try to run `screen`, it takes *forever* (on order of 20-30 secs).  Same thing if I run `screen -ls`, takes just as long.

I don't know if it has to do with where `screen` is configured?  But when I go to `$HOME`, there was no `.screenrc` file.  (So where is it? I read I can define my own location, so maybe this is a minor point...)

`screen -v` gives `Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06`

Does anyone have ideas on what the issue could be or is it just the way it is?

---

**Update 2**

1. I've tried setting environment variables `$SCREENDIR` and `$SCREENRC` to `~/.screenrc` and to a location on the server `/home/myusername`  = no change
2. I've tried a blank `.screenrc` file = no change
3. I've tried adding `defnonblock on` to `.screenrc` = no change
4. Also tried running strace with the additional `-f` option, but didn't notice any new info?

**strace file #2, snippet 1**, first occurrence of that funny number `4294967295`

```
11:24:23 connect(4, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/dev/log"...}, 110) = 0
11:24:23 sendto(4, "<14>Jun 25 11:24:23 screen: nss_"..., 129, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 129
11:24:23 write(3, "\27\3\1\0\33\331\331\30\274MD\374s\375ia\341!\200\16\4&\205\177\320\274\213\224gz\376l", 32) = 32
11:24:23 write(3, "\25\3\1\0\26\304\345w\317\273\257\256\322\314.\20T\372;'EQ\222\10z\375\234", 27) = 27
11:24:23 shutdown(3, 2 /* send and receive */) = 0
11:24:23 close(3)                       = 0
11:24:23 read(4294967295, 0xe5d3350, 5) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
11:24:23 shutdown(4294967295, 2 /* send and receive */) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
11:24:23 close(4294967295)              = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
11:24:23 stat("/etc/ldap.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=10681, ...}) = 0
11:24:23 geteuid()                      = 287621
11:24:23 open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY)   = 3
```

**New theory** : In-between those `nanosleep` calls, I see it's doing something with a unix auth server.  What is it doing or why... I don't know.  But then this line appears

> sendto(4, "<14>Jun 25 11:24:28 screen: nss_"..., 129, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 129

and I can't read the entire error message?? Then, the "Bad file descriptor" lines showup, and *bam*, going to sleep again.  Could understanding what it's doing with the unix auth server be key to understanding these delays?

**strace file #2, snippet 2**, zooming in on what happens before the sleeps occur.  Changed the company name and IP addresses to dummy values.

```
11:24:28 recvfrom(3, "\266!\201\200\0\1\0\2\0\0\0\0\10unixauth\2cs\6company\3"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("987.654.321.09")}, [16]) = 86
11:24:28 close(3)                       = 0
11:24:28 socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
11:24:28 fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)  = 0
11:24:28 setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [1], 4) = 0
11:24:28 setsockopt(3, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
11:24:28 fcntl(3, F_GETFL)              = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
11:24:28 fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 0
11:24:28 connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(636), sin_addr=inet_addr("123.456.789.01")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
11:24:28 poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 90000) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
11:24:28 getpeername(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(636), sin_addr=inet_addr("123.456.789.01")}, [4294967312]) = 0
11:24:28 fcntl(3, F_GETFL)              = 0x802 (flags O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)
11:24:28 fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)      = 0
11:24:28 write(3, "\200w\1\3\1\0N\0\0\0 \0\0009\0\0008\0\0005\0\0\26\0\0\23\0\0\n\7\0\300"..., 121) = 121
11:24:28 read(3, "\26\3\1\0Q\2\0", 7)   = 7
11:24:28 read(3, "\0M\3\1^\270\3\2\277\353\23\377\211\336\255Q\213\342\272\236@\242\252\5\357T\254\207\326\377Jl"..., 79) = 79
11:24:28 read(3, "\26\3\1\16\356", 5)   = 5
11:24:28 read(3, "\v\0\16\352\0\16\347\0\4\2520\202\4\2460\202\3\216\240\3\2\1\2\2\3\v\334/0\r\6\t"..., 3822) = 3822
11:24:28 read(3, "\26\3\1\0\4", 5)      = 5
11:24:28 read(3, "\16\0\0\0", 4)        = 4
11:24:28 write(3, "\26\3\1\0\206\20\0\0\202\0\200+\34JE5\2234\204I\233g@&m\4\232\317\335\323\373\366"..., 186) = 186
11:24:28 read(3, "\24\3\1\0\1", 5)      = 5
11:24:28 read(3, "\1", 1)               = 1
11:24:28 read(3, "\26\3\1\0$", 5)       = 5
11:24:28 read(3, "j\213\362\240R\244\35\257\243/\311\307\360\206\362\314\3\227\353\351\243\242=\222k\0y\367\20\\[\245"..., 36) = 36
11:24:28 write(3, "\27\3\1\0\214\216\374\314\342\264p\205j?\311\356#d\200\25]1\256\371\341\215\325\275jj\26\273"..., 145) = 145
11:24:28 poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 90000) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
11:24:28 read(3, "\27\3\1\0\255", 5)    = 5
11:24:28 read(3, "s\315\357J\363\342\37\10\r\251\333v\302\357\207\3429\3633\345\5\17j\35*K\216\300\225,\r\265"..., 173) = 173
11:24:28 sendto(4, "<14>Jun 25 11:24:28 screen: nss_"..., 129, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 129
11:24:28 write(3, "\27\3\1\0\33H\6eq\267(\356\35\366i\364H\372m\17O\7\307d;&\37\345f\212\320H", 32) = 32
11:24:28 write(3, "\25\3\1\0\26\245\267\236\270a\356\227\233\243e\0[3\372\226\33\342f\306\257[ ", 27) = 27
11:24:28 shutdown(3, 2 /* send and receive */) = 0
11:24:28 close(3)                       = 0
11:24:28 read(4294967295, 0xe5d3350, 5) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
11:24:28 shutdown(4294967295, 2 /* send and receive */) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
11:24:28 close(4294967295)              = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
11:24:28 sendto(4, "<14>Jun 25 11:24:28 screen: nss_"..., 89, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 89
11:24:28 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
11:24:28 rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
11:24:28 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
11:24:28 nanosleep({8, 0}, {8, 0})      = 0
```

---

**Update 1**
Here's the strace interesting bits... I see it's doing `nanosleep` repeatedly (each doubling the sleep time) but why?

```
09:10:05 read(4294967295, 0xca3b350, 5) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
09:10:05 shutdown(4294967295, 2 /* send and receive */) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
09:10:05 close(4294967295)              = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
09:10:05 sendto(4, "<14>Jun 25 09:10:05 screen: nss_"..., 89, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 89
09:10:05 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
09:10:05 rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
09:10:05 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
09:10:05 nanosleep({4, 0}, {4, 0})      = 0
09:10:12 stat("/etc/ldap.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=10681, ...}) = 0
09:10:12 geteuid()                      = 287621
09:10:12 open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY)   = 3
09:10:12 fcntl(3, F_GETFD)              = 0
...
09:10:20 read(4294967295, 0xca3b350, 5) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
09:10:20 shutdown(4294967295, 2 /* send and receive */) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
09:10:20 close(4294967295)              = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
09:10:20 sendto(4, "<14>Jun 25 09:10:20 screen: nss_"..., 90, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 90
09:10:20 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
09:10:20 rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
09:10:20 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
09:10:20 nanosleep({16, 0}, {16, 0})    = 0
09:10:36 stat("/etc/ldap.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=10681, ...}) = 0
09:10:36 geteuid()                      = 287621
09:10:36 open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY)   = 3
09:10:36 fcntl(3, F_GETFD)              = 0
...
09:10:36 write(3, "\27\3\1\0\33P\314s\21L-y\316\324\0\345!hd\212\351Q\33\345\335K\3\22\260r\312\332", 32) = 32 
09:10:36 write(3, "\25\3\1\0\26V\20\224{t2\364\250k\241\363\363\337V\370\236m\261I\240xw", 27) = 27 
09:10:36 shutdown(3, 2 /* send and receive */) = 0 
09:10:36 close(3)                       = 0 
09:10:36 read(4294967295, 0xca3b350, 5) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor) 
09:10:36 shutdown(4294967295, 2 /* send and receive */) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor) 
09:10:36 close(4294967295)              = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor) 
09:10:36 sendto(4, "<14>Jun 25 09:10:36 screen: nss_"..., 90, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 90 
09:10:36 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0 
09:10:36 rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0 
09:10:36 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0 
09:10:36 nanosleep({32, 0}, {32, 0})    = 0 
09:11:08 stat("/etc/ldap.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=10681, ...}) = 0 
09:11:08 geteuid()                      = 287621 
09:11:08 open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY)   = 3 
09:11:08 fcntl(3, F_GETFD)              = 0 
09:11:08 fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)  = 0 
...
09:11:08 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0 
09:11:08 rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0 
09:11:08 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0 
09:11:08 nanosleep({64, 0}, {64, 0})    = 0 
09:12:12 stat("/etc/ldap.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=10681, ...}) = 0 
09:12:12 geteuid()                      = 287621 
09:12:12 open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY)   = 3 
09:12:12 fcntl(3, F_GETFD)              = 0
```

Comment: Run it through strace and post the part around the delay (if there is a special one): `strace -t -o screen.strace screen -ls`

Comment: Is it only screen takes so long time or your server is highly loaded and any command runs a long time?

Comment: @HaukeLaging - I get this error with the command you provided: "Directory '/var/run/screen' must have mode 777."

Comment: @slm: then you should `chmod 777 /var/run/screen`. After all, it's no big deal to change permissions to something else than the rpm provides. :-) (with which I agree, by the way)

Comment: @slm But screen works for you, the error message does not appear without strace? Here `ls -ld /var/run/screens/ /var/run/uscreens/` leads to 755 and 1777.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - OK, thanks for the clarification, not that adept at using `strace`. Working on mastering it. I see you use it all the time, so I was trying to follow along to get some more experience with it.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I got the `Directory '/var/run/screen' must have mode 777` error too. But I can't change it since I'm not root.

Comment: If your screen is not SUID root then you can use `$SCREENDIR` to set another directory. If it is SUID root then you may simply copy the binary (the SUID bit gets erased by that). In order not to miss updates you may copy it again from your shell startup scripts.

Comment: The `read(4294967295,` seems evil to me. That happens to be 2^32-1. It may be possible to force the usage of that FD (if the kernel uses unsigned 32 bit for them what I don't know but doubt) but why should anyone do that? May be a bug. You could search the strace output for the first appearance of this number. And it may be useful to add a `-f` to the `strace` call.

Comment: Total guess: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/screen/+bug/600999. Workaround in that thread was this: `echo "defnonblock on" >> ~/.screenrc`.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - I'm not familiar with the syscalls, so unsure what that first parameter to `read` represents...
@slm - no luck

Comment: I don't know whether that is the reason for the problem but the `read(4294967295,` is obviously a bug then. File descriptors have to be passed by a syscall before they may be used. Except for the inherited ones (0, 1, and 2: stdin, stdout, and stderr).

Comment: Did you check if there is an /etc/screenrc that may be loading something strange?

Comment: thanks, ill strace mine.  having this issue.  for yours, i would suspect bad file descriptor. could mean 1) fd already closed somewhere 2) fd has incorrect bad value, which is inconsistent with the value obtained from socket() api https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258781/bad-file-descriptor-with-linux-socket-write-bad-file-descriptor-c/11278981

Answer (score 1):

When we encountered this, our resident ops genius narrowed it down to a slow LDAP server.  The short-term fix was to remove the offending LDAP server from the `/etc/ldap.conf` file.