# GNU screen is very slow when it opens new window

Tags: ubuntu, gnu-screen

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and GNU screen version 4.06.02

Whenever the GNU screen opens a new window, it takes 5~6 seconds which is really annoying.

I have cleared `.screenrc`, but it still has same problem.

Also, I tried

```
echo "defnonblock on" >> ~/.screenrc
```

as mentioned in previous post ([GNU screen startup is really slow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80597)), but it didn't help.

I got following results by

```
strace -t -o screen.strace screen -ls
```

```
19:48:22 execve("/usr/bin/screen", ["screen", "-ls"], 0x7ffc5204d430 /* 30 vars */) = 0
19:48:22 brk(NULL)                      = 0x562370e41000
19:48:22 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
19:48:22 access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
19:48:22 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
19:48:22 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=97740, ...}) = 0
19:48:22 mmap(NULL, 97740, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f89b8ec1000
19:48:22 close(3)                       = 0
19:48:22 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
19:48:22 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
19:48:22 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\311\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
19:48:22 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=170784, ...}) = 0
19:48:22 mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f89b8ebf000
19:48:22 mmap(NULL, 2267936, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f89b8a88000
19:48:22 mprotect(0x7f89b8aad000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
19:48:22 mmap(0x7f89b8cad000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7f89b8cad000
19:48:22 close(3)                       = 0
19:48:22 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
19:48:22 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutempter.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
19:48:22 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\t\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
19:48:22 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=10160, ...}) = 0
19:48:22 mmap(NULL, 2105376, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f89b8885000
19:48:22 mprotect(0x7f89b8886000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
19:48:22 mmap(0x7f89b8a86000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7f89b8a86000
19:48:22 close(3)                       = 0
19:48:22 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
19:48:22 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
19:48:22 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\r\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
19:48:22 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=39208, ...}) = 0
19:48:22 mmap(NULL, 2322976, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f89b864d000
19:48:22 mprotect(0x7f89b8656000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
19:48:22 mmap(0x7f89b8855000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x8000) = 0x7f89b8855000
19:48:22 mmap(0x7f89b8857000, 184864, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f89b8857000
19:48:22 close(3)                       = 0
19:48:22 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
19:48:22 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
19:48:22 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`$\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
19:48:22 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=55848, ...}) = 0
19:48:22 mmap(NULL, 2150896, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f89b843f000
19:48:22 mprotect(0x7f89b844c000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
19:48:22 mmap(0x7f89b864b000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xc000) = 0x7f89b864b000
19:48:22 close(3)                       = 0
19:48:22 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
19:48:22 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
19:48:22 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
19:48:22 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2030544, ...}) = 0
19:48:22 mmap(NULL, 4131552, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f89b804e000
19:48:22 mprotect(0x7f89b8235000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
19:48:22 mmap(0x7f89b8435000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7f89b8435000
19:48:22 mmap(0x7f89b843b000, 15072, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f89b843b000
19:48:22 close(3)                       = 0
19:48:22 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
19:48:22 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
19:48:22 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`-\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
19:48:22 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=124848, ...}) = 0
19:48:22 mmap(NULL, 2261160, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f89b7e25000
19:48:22 mprotect(0x7f89b7e42000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
19:48:22 mmap(0x7f89b8042000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1d000) = 0x7f89b8042000
19:48:22 mmap(0x7f89b8044000, 37032, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f89b8044000
19:48:22 close(3)                       = 0
19:48:22 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
19:48:22 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
19:48:22 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
19:48:22 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14560, ...}) = 0
19:48:22 mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f89b8ebd000
19:48:22 mmap(NULL, 2109712, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f89b7c21000
19:48:22 mprotect(0x7f89b7c24000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
19:48:22 mmap(0x7f89b7e23000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f89b7e23000
19:48:22 close(3)                       = 0
19:48:22 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
19:48:22 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap-ng.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
19:48:22 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\23\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
19:48:22 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=18712, ...}) = 0
19:48:22 mmap(NULL, 2113848, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f89b7a1c000
19:48:22 mprotect(0x7f89b7a20000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
19:48:22 mmap(0x7f89b7c1f000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f89b7c1f000
19:48:22 close(3)                       = 0
19:48:22 mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f89b8eba000
19:48:22 arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f89b8eba740) = 0
19:48:22 mprotect(0x7f89b8435000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
19:48:22 mprotect(0x7f89b7c1f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
19:48:22 mprotect(0x7f89b7e23000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
19:48:22 mprotect(0x7f89b8042000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
19:48:22 mprotect(0x7f89b864b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
19:48:22 mprotect(0x7f89b8855000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
19:48:22 mprotect(0x7f89b8a86000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
19:48:22 mprotect(0x7f89b8cad000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
19:48:22 mprotect(0x56237033d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
19:48:22 mprotect(0x7f89b8ed9000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
19:48:22 munmap(0x7f89b8ec1000, 97740)  = 0
19:48:22 prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, NULL, {rlim_cur=10240*1024, rlim_max=10240*1024}) = 0
19:48:22 close(10485759)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
19:48:22 close(10485758)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
19:48:22 close(10485757)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
19:48:22 close(10485756)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
19:48:22 close(10485755)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
19:48:22 close(10485754)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
19:48:22 close(10485753)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
19:48:22 close(10485752)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
19:48:22 close(10485751)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
19:48:22 close(10485750)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
19:48:22 close(10485749)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
19:48:22 close(10485748)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
19:48:22 close(10485747)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
19:48:22 close(10485746)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
19:48:22 close(10485745)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
19:48:22 close(10485744)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
19:48:22 close(10485743)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
19:48:22 close(10485742)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
19:48:22 close(10485741)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
19:48:22 close(10485740)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
19:48:22 close(10485739)                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
...
```

I need help to solve this problem.

Comment: 19:48:22 to 19:48:22 is not 5 seconds.

Comment: Probably something in your `~/.bashrc`, look at `bash -x ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I resolved the issue with proper security limit using command `ulimit -n 10000`. The default value (i.e., limit for open files) is 1024, and I changed the value to 10485760 which might produce the problem.

Comment: So what exactly did u do? running command `ulimit -n 10000` or `ulimit -n 10485760` or what? @ilios86